# Hey I need help making the backend for a "bookshop" gui

Tags: python, sqlite

So here is the problem, I'm trying to make the first value update to be a different entry, but it keeps giving me this error:

```
line 50, in <module>
    update(1, "The Moon", "John Smooth", 1917, 99999999)
TypeError: update() takes 0 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Can anybody figure out what this error means, and the solution to it? Oh also ignore the #s those were for testing other functions of the bookshop.

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()
   
def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    
def view():
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
    rows=cr.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows
    
def search(title="",author="",year="",isbn=""):
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?", (title, author, year, isbn))
    rows=cr.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows

def delete(id):
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("DELETE FROM book WHERE id=?",(id,))
    con.commit()
    con.close() 

def update():
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?, author=?, year=?, isbn=?",(id,title,author,year,isbn))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

connect()
insert("The Sun", "John Smith", 1918, 193123132)
#delete(3)
update(1, "The Moon", "John Smooth", 1917, 99999999)
print(view())
#print(search(author="John Smitch"))
```

Comment: Is the error very obvious stated what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As an example, take a look at your other methods.  For example, `search`.  There you define 4 method arguments:

```
def search(title="",author="",year="",isbn=""):
```

And you use those arguments:

```
cr.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?", (title, author, year, isbn))
```

Now take a look at your `update` method.  You define 0 arguments:

```
def update():
```

And you try to use 5 arguments:

```
cr.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?, author=?, year=?, isbn=?",(id,title,author,year,isbn))
```

And, specifically to the cause of the error, you try to pass those 5 arguments when calling the method:

```
update(1, "The Moon", "John Smooth", 1917, 99999999)
```

The method expects 0 arguments, but 5 are given.  If you want to pass arguments to the method, make it expect them, just like you already do in your other methods:

```
def update(id,title,author,year,isbn):
```